# Playing cutscenes in c++

Tags: c++, opengl, video, sdl

I'm using SDL for opening a window and handeling events. And OpenGL to render my objects to the screen. SDL_mixer for sound, and SDL_ttf for text. Now I'm trying to figure out how to be able to put a video on display. Like an animated logo or something before the game starts. Just to experiment with it. At some point I will need to know it...

I've found and tried installing FFMPEG, I've included the "include" folder, and set the "lib" folder. At first I got an error telling me it was unable to load "inttypes.h". So I downloaded a package with that and put it in the include folder for FFMPEG.

Now I'm stuck with this error, which I can't seem to be able to solve.

> c:\program
>   files\ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win64-dev\include\libavutil\common.h(87):
>   fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found

And another question, is there other libraries aviable that may be easier to use for displaying a simple video? I read something about SDL being able to do it, but nothing was to be found about it.

EDIT: Here is line 78 to 96:

```
#if FF_API_AV_REVERSE
extern attribute_deprecated const uint8_t av_reverse[256];
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H
#   include "config.h"
#   include "intmath.h"
#endif

/* Pull in unguarded fallback defines at the end of this file. */
#include "common.h"

#ifndef av_log2
av_const int av_log2(unsigned v);
#endif

#ifndef av_log2_16bit
av_const int av_log2_16bit(unsigned v);
#endif
```

Comment: Without seeing line 87 of `common.h`, my best guess is this is some sort of pre-processor error (e.g. unmatched `#if` / `#endif`). Any chance you could actually add 2 or 3 lines from around line 87?

Comment: I have no idea where this file is, it's not one of mine. I'll see if I can find it.

Answer (score 1):

[Wrap your `#include <libav*.h>`s inside a block like this:](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Including%20FFmpeg%20headers%20in%20a%20C%2B%2B%20application)

```
#ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#define UNDEFINE_STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif
extern "C"
{
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavdevice/version.h>
}
#ifdef UNDEFINE_STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#undef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif
```

There's *probably* a way around using the `UNDEFINE_STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` hack but the logic just isn't coming to me right now.

Worked for me on VS2012 using [Zeranoe's 32-bit ffmpeg development binaries](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and [msinttypes' `inttypes.h`](https://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/source/browse/trunk/inttypes.h).

Comment: this din't quite work for me. I get complaints about 'UINT64_C': identifier not found. Maybe I need the does the download page mean 32-bit VISUAL STUDIO or WINDOWS? I thought it meant Windows, but I guess ill try the 32 to check

Comment: Nope, didn't make a difference. Stuck with the UINT64_C error!

Comment: @AleksanderFimreite: See my edit about `inttypes.h`.  I was using the 32-bit binaries.

Comment: I tried the 32-bit version as well. It doesn't work for me. Where did you place your inttypes.h file? mine is in ...\ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win32-dev\include

Comment: @AleksanderFimreite: Same place.

Comment: I tried creating a new program with only SDL + FFmpeg, this time it runs with the exact same including! May this library have issues with some other libraries?

Comment: However, I get an error of "Can't start because 'avformat-55.dll' is missing." I didn't get any dll-files with my download of FFmpeg, where can I find all those?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I found the DLL-files, and it gave me a linker error with the 64-bit library.
I changed back to 32-bit and the 32-bit dlls and it worked fine. I guess that libraries ask if you have 32/64-bit Visual Studio insteath of Windows.

Comment: And about it working in my other project. Apparently, it doesn't like being included AFTER #include <glm>!